# Como Detectar se o usuário utiliza AdBlock e tomar uma decisão com base na resposta?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um problema com o *Banner do Ebit*
Quando o usuário tem o algum Adblocker instalado ele fica rodando em loop e sobrecarrega o navegador porque a página não para de recarregar e trava
Eu quero identificar se a pessoa tem *Adblock* e, se sim, nem carregar o banner, caso contrário, carregar normalmente.

Tentei utilizar o *FuckAdblock* para fazer isso, mas quando tenho dificuldade para inserir o banner depois da resposta negativa.

**O código abaixo é uma versão resumida do necessário para o banner carregar.**

```
<param/> <!-- parâmetros do consumidor -->
<a id="bannerEbit"></a> <!-- Aqui é carregado o Banner com o background e o link -->
<script id="getSelo" src="ebit.com.br/getselo"> <!-- Chama o script do ebit -->
```

Comment: "_tenho dificuldade para inserir o banner depois da resposta negativa_".. qual seria a dificuldade?

Comment: eu coloquei um document.write('<a id="bannerEbit"></a>') caso a pessoa não tenha adblock, mas assim ele não "sincroniza" com o script e não carrega o banner. Sem contar que assim ele carrega esse <a>, mas ignora todo o resto da página

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o script que carrega o banner via JavaScript dentro da função onde não é detectado o AdBlock.

Coloque normalmente as tags `<param>` e `<a id="bannerEbit"></a>` no seu HTML.

Na função onde o FuckAdblock detecta que não existe AdBlock, insira este código que irá adicionar dinamicamente o `<script>` do eBit na página e irá carregar na página o banner de anúncio:

```
function adBlockNotDetected() {
   var s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
   s.src = "https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?storeId&lightbox=true";
   s.id = "getSelo";
   document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

> Em `s.src`, coloque as informações correspondentes à sua conta.

[Documentação do FuckAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock)

Solução detalhada **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289510/8063)**.

Comment: Deu certo e ele carregou o banner quando não tem Adblock, mas, quando tem, ele continua conseguindo detectar o banner e entra em loop porque o banner fica tentando carregar. Eu devo colocar alguma coisa dentro da função que detecta que o Adblock existe para parar o carregamento do banner?

Comment: mas teoricamente esse id nem existiria porque está na outra função :(

Comment: Se eu mandar o link da página será que você consegue entender EXATAMENTE a questão?

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Dá uma olhada nesta página de teste, veja os alertas. Está funcionando perfeito com uma parte do código que peguei do seu site: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Quando o Adblock é detectado, não faz nada. Deixa a função em branco.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara. Na loja continua dando loop, talvez o problema não seja o banner em si. Obrigado pelo seu tempo

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Vou continuar vendo aqui... tem que achar a solução

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71137/discussion-between-ciano-barbarossa-and-dvd).

Comment: Andy, Bom dia. Se puder me ajudar hoje...

Comment: Cara, preciso mais uma vez da sua ajuda com o Ebit

Comment: Tem como adicionar um outro endereço aqui?

Comment: <?php 
if ( !strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , '**gerencianet/success&payment**') ){ 
?> 
<a id="seloEbit" href="http://www.ebit.com.br/90809" target="_blank" data-noop="redir(this.href);"> </a> 
<script type="text/javascript" id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?90809"> </script> 
<?php 
} 
?>