# Banner do ebit com erro 404 e loop infinito com adblock ligado

Tags: javascript, http-status-404

Olá, estou tentando implementar o banner do ebit na loja virtual do woocommerce. Adicionei linhas de códigos que a ebit me enviou mas quando faço ele rodar, apareceram 2 erros.

Resolvi criar uma página vazia em html e coloquei somente o código do banner:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="bannerEbit"></a>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?93414"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Eu consigo ver a imagem do banner no navegador mas quando vejo o console, ele mostra uma menssagem de erro

`GET https://empresa.ebit.com.br/bitrate/banners/b1934145.gif   404 ()`

**1-** Alguém saberia o que poderia ser ou se esse erro influenciaria na loja?

**2-** Quando eu uso o Adblock, não sei direito o que acontece mas ele começa a motrar outro erro (abaixo) e entra em looping infinito. Existe alguma forma de contornar essa situação?

```
GET https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner.gif?storeId=93414 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Já pesquisei no fórum [Como Detectar se o usuário utiliza AdBlock e tomar uma decisão com base na resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266646/como-detectar-se-o-usu%C3%A1rio-utiliza-adblock-e-tomar-uma-decis%C3%A3o-com-base-na-respo) mas não consegui resolver meu problema. :/

Comment: Isto não é um problema de programação, é um bug no script que fica tentando chamar o GIF por achar que foi uma falha na conexão, não tem nada que possamos fazer, só o adm do ebit pode resolver... Ainda sim você pode experimentar usar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87992/3635 antes de carregar o `.js`

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar usar ele! Brigada :D

Comment: Grande chance de ter problema com refer(r)er. Provavelmente o ebit só fornece o banner pro domínio correto (ou sem domínio, no caso do teste direto). Tem que testar no domínio original para qual o ID foi definido.

Comment: Andrea eu postei uma resposta com um exemplo de como usar com o ebit.

Comment: O erro 404 some se vc inserir o selo em vez do banner: `<a id="seloEbit"></a>`... quando insere o banner dá o erro 404, deve ser um bug mesmo do script ou algum tipo de contagem que eles fazem em background.

Comment: Só pra constar, fuckAdblock (https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock) é o mesmo que blockAdblock (https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock), criado pelo mesmo autor, ou seja o script que postei na minha resposta não muda em nada em relação da segunda resposta e o problema do loop era sim um "bug" por causa desta linha no getSelo.js: `a.onerror=function(){a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters?"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp+"&"+ebitBannerParameters.value:"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp}`

Comment: Pronto, resposta editada com detalhes adicionados: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289499/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme dito, o erro mostrado no console pode ser um bug no script do eBit ou algum tipo de controle que eles fazem ao chamar o arquivo `.gif`(?).

Se você usar `<a id="seloEbit"></a>` em vez de `<a id="bannerEbit"></a>`, o erro desaparece exibindo o selo do eBit, porém não mostra o banner, mas não é isso que deseja. Era só para explicar.

Se você colocar as duas tags, irá mostrar o selo e o banner:

```
<a id="seloEbit"></a>
<a id="bannerEbit"></a>
```

---

Em relação aos bloqueadores de anúncios, para evitar looping infinito, você pode usar o [fuckadblock](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fuckadblock).

Deixe apenas a tag `<a id="bannerEbit"></a>` no local onde você deseja que exiba o banner e não coloque o script `<script type="text/javascript" id="getSelo" src="https://imgs.ebit....`, ele será inserido pelo código. Basta inserir o código abaixo (veja comentários no código):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   function adBlockNotDetected() {
      //Gera o Banner do Ebit caso não tenha bloqueador ativado
      var s = document.createElement("script"); 
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = "https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?93414";
      s.id = "getSelo";
      document.body.appendChild(s);
   }

   function adBlockDetected() {
      // faz alguma coisa caso tenha bloqueador ativado
      console.log("Anúncios bloqueados");
   }

   if(typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined') { 
      adBlockDetected(); 
   } else { 

      var importFAB = document.createElement('script'); 
      importFAB.onload = function() { 
         fuckAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected) 
         fuckAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected); 
      }
      importFAB.onerror = function() { 
         adBlockDetected(); 
      }
      importFAB.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js'; 
      document.head.appendChild(importFAB); 
   }
});
</script>
```

> ### Dica:
>
> Caso haja algum bloqueador de anúncios ativado, você pode inserir uma
>   banner padrão na tag `<a id="bannerEbit"></a>` para que não fique
>   vazia. Basta inserir um código que insira uma imagem na função
>   `adBlockDetected() {...}`.

Comment: Opa! Funcionou direitinho! Muito grata pela ajuda :D

Comment: De nada. Fico feliz em ajudar.

Comment: Uma dica: salve o arquivo `fuckadblock.min.js` no seu servidor. Vai que um dia ele saia do ar lá no CDN e aí vai dar problema :).

Comment: hmm vdd! Ja vou salvar. thx

Comment: Pois eh, salve nos seus diretórios e aponte para ele, fica até mais rápido do que puxar remotamente

Answer (score 1):

Isto não é um problema de programação, é um BUG no script https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js que fica tentando chamar o GIF quando ocorre erro ao baixa-lo, o script pensa que foi erro no download e ou falha na conexão e fica tentando baixar o GIF, o problema é nesta linha:

```
var a=new Image;a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters?"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/b1"+ebitNumEmp+"5"+t+".gif?"+ebitBannerParameters.value:"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/b1"+ebitNumEmp+"5"+t+".gif",a.style.border="0px",a.onerror=function(){a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters?"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp+"&"+ebitBannerParameters.value:"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp}
```

Ajustando o código para melhor visibilidade:

```
var a=new Image;

    a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters ? "https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/b1"+ebitNumEmp+"5"+t+".gif?"+ebitBannerParameters.value :
                                       "https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/b1"+ebitNumEmp+"5"+t+".gif",

    a.style.border="0px",

    a.onerror=function(){
         a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters ? "https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp+"&"+ebitBannerParameters.value :
                                            "https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp
    }
```

Então veja, quando o *adblock* bloqueia essa imagem, então `onerror` é dispara, no `onerror` novamente é tentado setar o `.src` de `new Image`, mas como obviamente o adblock ainda está bloqueando isto então irá entrar novamente no `onerror`, e isto ficará até desativar o adblock, ou seja neste momento irá ficar tentando carregar em loop/ciclo a imagem, até que consiga. Não é algo que possamos resolver, é falha no `getSelo.js`.

Pra concluir não tem nada que possamos fazer, só o administrador do site ebit pode resolver.

> Só pra constar `FuckBlock` e `BlockAdBlock` são o mesmo script, não mudam em nada, somente o nome, o autor criou o BlockAdBlock somente para evitar que quem fosse usar o script não passasse por algum constrangimento com cliente ou pessoas, mas o script de fato é o mesmo:
>
> - https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock
> - https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock

Ainda sim você pode experimentar usar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87992/3635 antes de carregar o `.js`, assim por exemplo:

```
<script src="blockAdBlock.js"></script>
<script>
//Detect se o documento carregou
document.addEvent('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    //Se não detectar o adblock aplica o ebit
    function adBlockNotDetected() {
        var ebit = document.createElement("script");

        ebit.src = "https://imgs.ebit.com.br/ebitBR/selo-ebit/js/getSelo.js?93414";
        document.body.appendChild(ebit);
    }

    //Se detectar o adblock
    function adBlockDetected() {
        alert('AdBlock está ativado');
    }

    if(typeof blockAdBlock=== 'undefined') {
        alert("blockAdBlock não foi carregado");
    } else {
        blockAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(false, adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected).onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
    }

    blockAdBlock.setOption('checkOnLoad', false);

    blockAdBlock.setOption({
        debug: true,
        checkOnLoad: false,
        resetOnEnd: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: "_que fica tentando chamar o GIF quando ocorre erro ao baixa-lo, o script pensa que foi erro no download e ou falha na conexão e fica tentando baixar o GIF._".. não é isso que acontece.. o problema é que se tiver um adblock ativo no navegador fica dando looping infinito.. o erro do gif nada tem a ver com isso. Trabalho com Ebit há pelo menos uns 10 anos.

Comment: Corrigindo, há uns 5 anos... confundi com Mercado Livre... rs

Comment: @dvd O navegador não dá loop sozinho, isso não tem sentido, que faz o loop em é o script. O GIF não é uma linguagem que auto detecta falhas e recarrega, se fosse assim o .gif do analytics teria o mesmo problema (sim o analitycs também chama um gif em certas ocasiões ou falta de suporte) ... E só pra constar o FuckBlock é o mesmo que o blockAdblock, só muda de nome.

Comment: @dvd pra constar o loop é bem evidente nesta linha do script js: `a.onerror=function(){a.src=null!=ebitBannerParameters?"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp+"&"+ebitBannerParameters.value:"https://www.ebitempresa.com.br/bitrate/banners/banner"+t+".gif?storeId="+ebitNumEmp}`, ocorre o `onerror` então ele tenta setar o `src`, então ***sim*** isto é considerado um **loop/ciclo**.