# FuckAdBlock so reconhece que o adBlock esta desligado depois de muitos refresh na pagina

Tags: javascript, ad

Ola, estou tentando implementar o banner do ebit mas estou tendo problemas com o adBlocks.
Na minha pergunta anterior ([Banner do ebit com erro 404 e loop infinito com adblock ligado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289492/banner-do-ebit-com-erro-404-e-loop-infinito-com-adblock-ligado)) consegui implementar o fuckAdBlock para bloquear os anuncios, porem ele nao esta reconhecendo quando o adBlock não esta ativado. Somente depois de varios refreshs na pagina que ele funciona.

Esse é meu codigo:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   function adBlockNotDetected() {
     console.log('anuncio NAO bloqueado');
 }

 // Function called if AdBlock is detected
  function adBlockDetected() {
      //>>esta bloqueando mesmo sem o adBlock estar ativo<<
      console.log("Anuncios bloqueados");
  }
  
  if(typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined') {     
      adBlockDetected(); 
  } else {     
      var importFAB = document.createElement('script'); 

      importFAB.onload = function() {          
          fuckAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
          fuckAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
      }


      importFAB.onerror = function() {        
          adBlockDetected(); 
      }

      importFAB.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js'; 
      document.head.appendChild(importFAB);
  }
 });
 </script>
```

Achei um post parecido com o meu 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980660/detect-ad-block-script-runs-properly-only-on-hard-reload
mas quando eu adiciono o `fuckAdBlock.check(loop);` ele acusa erro.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ fuckAdBlock.check(loop); });
```

Não sei se escrevi certo, pq eu não queria usar o jQuery....

Comment: Ele está detectando "ativado" mesmo sem o adblock estar ativado?

Comment: sim. Ele esta caindo sempre na funcao adBlockDetected() e so depois que atualizo a pagina varias vezes é q ele reconhece que o adblock nao esta ativo

Comment: qual adblock vc tá usando?

Comment: adblock da https://getadblock.com/
versao 3.28.0
e estou usando o chrome

Comment: mas eu desativei ele para fazer o teste, e mesmo assim esta acusando que ele esta ativado.

Comment: vou instalar pra testar, pode ser que não detecte, vai saber

Comment: é esse adblock que uso tb

Comment: e nao deu nenhum problema?

Comment: vou testar de novo aqui

Comment: abre [esta página](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php) e teste... abra o console para ver as mensagens... funciona normal

Comment: hmmm q estranho, aqui ainda esta aparecendo a mensagem de "Anuncios bloqueados" no console....

Comment: vou tentar desisntalar o adblock e ver no que da

Comment: na página de teste? mesmo com o Adblock desativado?

Comment: pra mim funciona normal quando ativo ou desativo o adblock.

Comment: bom, entao vai ver é coisa do meu pc kkkk. Se ai aparece normal entao acho q nao deve ter problema

Comment: vc desinstalou? o que apareceu com ele desinstalado?

Comment: Talvez seja interessante testar em outro navegador

Comment: No opera funcionou!!!! Entao deve ser coisa do meu chrome.

Comment: vlw pela ajuda! e desculpe por tomar seu tempo ^^'

Comment: Imagina! Se precisar tamos aí.